# SQL server database isolation level for web application

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, hibernate, activiti

I am building a java based web application that works on SQL server.

Default database isolation level of SQL server is READ_COMMITTED.

I get a following exception:

```
 Cause: org.hibernate.exception.LockAcquisitionException: Transaction (Process ID 124) was deadlocked on lock resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction.

    2016-08-18 07:23:36.064 ERROR application 

    Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Transaction (Process ID 124) was deadlocked on lock resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction.
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:216) ~[com.microsoft.sqlserver.sqljdbc4-4.0.jar:na]
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerResultSet$FetchBuffer.nextRow(SQLServerResultSet.java:4853) ~[com.microsoft.sqlserver.sqljdbc4-4.0.jar:na]
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerResultSet.fetchBufferNext(SQLServerResultSet.java:1781) ~[com.microsoft.sqlserver.sqljdbc4-4.0.jar:na]
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerResultSet.next(SQLServerResultSet.java:1034) ~[com.microsoft.sqlserver.sqljdbc4-4.0.jar:na]
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor25.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_74]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_74]
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractResultSetProxyHandler.continueInvocation(AbstractResultSetProxyHandler.java:104) ~[org.hibernate.hibernate-core-4.1.9.Final.jar:4.1.9.Final]
        ... 82 common frames omitted
```

Can someone give more information about it?

Comment: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178104%28v=sql.105%29.aspx

Comment: Same application works pretty alright without deadlocks on Mariadb, I am a bit confused with that.

Answer (score 1):

By default sql server uses pessimistic locking. This means when a row is read or updated within a transaction it is locked by that transaction so no other transaction can read or write to it (the other transaction will block until the first transaction is committed)

A deadlock occurs when you have 2 transactions reading the same data and both lock a row that the other transaction was reading.

Taking a simple example:
You have a table with on column called name and 2 rows:

Name:
Foo
Bar

Transaction 1 reads Foo (causing it to lock)
Transaction 2 reads Bar (causing it to lock)
Transaction 1 tries to read Bar but will block until transaction 2 commits
Transaction 2 tries to read Foo but is blocked by transaction 1

You now have a deadlock, both transactions are waiting for the other to release the resource. Sql server has an internal mechanism to detect deadlocks, it will detect the deadlock and pick one transaction to roll back. The java thread with the transaction which is chosen as the deadlock victim will return an error like your example.

The solution:
Here you have a few options

1. If possible, change your code so that the rows that are read are always read in the same order (in the example above if both transactions read foo first transaction 2 will simply wait for transaction 1 to complete)
2. Accept that deadlocks can be a part of concurrent applications and either allow the user to resubmit the request or create some code that can resubmit the request automatically if this error is thrown. (not ideal but depending on the frequency of the problem it is sometimes pragmatic to allow these errors to occur occasionally)
3. Look at alternative locking strategies. SQL server supports several but they can broadly be categorised in to 2 categories, pessimistic locking (the default and the same in your example) and optimistic locking (sometimes referred to as snapshot isolation).
   Optimistic locking allows multiple transactions to READ the same row without a lock, a lock is only required for writing. There are pros and cons to both methods and changing this could move the problem.
    
   In the example above optimistic locking would solve this as the two transactions are only reading. If however the two transactions were inserting or updating records you may simply move the problem in that with optimistic locking if 2 transactions try to update the same record (after both transactions have read but neither have committed) the transaction to commit last would get an optimistic lock error. 
   There are many other areas to consider and some good articles are available that go into much more detail.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj856598(v=sql.110).aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tcbchxcb(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

MS SQLServer uses a different isolation level than most databases and as a result the default READ_COMMITTED will probably interfere with the operation of the process engine under production load conditions.

The following article from Camunda (which is a fork of the Activiti engine) suggests the following work around:

https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.5/user-guide/process-engine/database/#custom-configuration-for-microsoft-sql-server